Characters get stuck on screen when using tmux
I use LazyVim on Alacritty on WSL, and when using it in tmux the screen doesn't display properly. Random characters get "stuck" on screen and won't clear until I do something that forces that line to update. For example, this page should be blank since I've searched for a nonsense string, but it seems like a few characters from some of the file paths persist:

Using it outside of Tmux is fine. I'm using tmux -u to start tmux.

The issue was a conflict between tmux and vim about how wide certain characters were. The problem only occurs on Alacritty, so switching to WezTerm resolved it.
